# Why is this explicit cast causing problems only with a Linked Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, linked-server

I am querying data from a linked server through a view on the origin server.
The view has to include a couple of standardized columns, such as `Created`, `Modified` and `Deleted`, but in this case the table on the source server doesn't have any suitable info. The columns are therefore explicitly cast to their respective types. I updated the view, changing a column from

```
NULL AS Modified
```

to

```
CAST(NULL as DateTime) as Modified
```

However, after performing this update, the view is triggering the following error message:

> Msg 7341, Level 16, State 2, Line 3
>   Cannot get the current row value of column "(user generated expression).Expr1002" from OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "".

We have done this "explicit cast"-change generally across the origin server without worries, and I suspect the issue might be related to the version of the servers involved. We don't really *need* to apply this cast, but it feels cleaner. Right now I'm just curious as to why this is happening.

Server Version (origin):

> Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.5058.0 (X64)   May 14 2014 18:34:29   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)

Server Version (linked):

> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1) - 10.50.2500.0 (X64)   Jun 17 2011 00:54:03   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)

**Edit**
I just realized I made a mistake by not posting all the columns in question, and I must apologize for leaving out an important detail. I don't know how I didn't notice this sooner. The question still remains, though.

*The erroneous cast does not happen with the cast to DateTime, but with a column being cast to UniqueIdentifier.*

**This** is the culprit:

```
CAST(NULL AS UniqueIdentifier) AS [GUID]
```

UniqueIdentifiers are supported on SQL Server 2008 R2, and as mentioned in the comments, the query performed by the view runs fine on the linked server.

Comment: Do you have a different ANSI NULL setting on each server? Different collation?

Comment: Both servers have ANSI NULL = 0. Origin server has the collation `Danish_Norwegian_CI_AS` and the linked server has the collation `SQL_Danish_Pref_CP1_CI_AS`, but the `COLLATE` clause cannot be applied to `DateTime` columns, so I didn't get much further!

Comment: Would this fail if have `select Null  from ...` in WITH or nested query and `CAST` in another?

Comment: Without the explicit cast it will be treated as `INT` so you have changed the datatype by doing so. I don't know why that would give you that error message though.

Comment: I had previously tried to wrap the selected values with actual values in a CTE, then select them and tack on the casted NULLs in the statement following the CTE with no luck. I tried your suggestion, keeping the NULLs in the CTE and casting them in the statement querying the CTE, but it also yields the same error.

Comment: Too late to correct a typo in previous comment: "wrap the columns with actual values in a CTE" *

Comment: Have you tried selecting from the view from the actual source server.  I'm trying to see if the 'view' is the problem and not something to do with the linked server.  The more things we can eliminate from the mix, the smaller our focus can become

Comment: Hey Scott. I've executed the view-statement from a session on the linked server, and it works fine. Something weird is happening along the way..

Comment: Out of curiosity, could you select top 0 into a new real table the results of the view on the source database.  Script the new table from the source and recreate it on the target.  I'd also be curious about removing any script SET ansi, blah statements before creating on the new server.  Then use your linked server to insert into the newly created targer table.

Comment: you could cast to varchar, then uniqueidentifier. CAST (CAST(null as varchar(max)) as uniqueidentifier) as [GUID]

Comment: What SP level are you at on the SQL Server 2012 instance? I am running 2012 with SP3 and cannot reproduce this. If you aren't sure, then you can update the question with the output from `SELECT @@VERSION;`.

Comment: @ScottHodgin I did as you suggested. The `select into`-operation output a table with nullable DateTime- and UniqueIdentifier-columns, as expected. Filling with data from view query executed on linked server works fine. Recreating with `ANSI_NULLS` off and filling again made no difference.

Comment: @BobKlimes Hey Bob, thank you. I tried your suggestion and it does indeed work (although cast to `nvarchar` doesn't work for some reason). I still need to understand why this is happening before I apply a workaround.

Comment: @srutzky I updated the question with full version-output from both involved servers, thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So, I was able to reproduce the error after realizing that the `CAST` was being done locally, not on the remote instance. I had previously recommended moving up to SP3 in the hopes of fixing this (partially due to not being able to reproduce the error on SP3, and partially due to it being a good idea regardless). However, now that I can reproduce the error, it is clear that moving up to SP3, while still probably a good idea, is not going to fix this. And I also reproduced the error in SQL Server 2008 R2 RTM and 2014 SP1 (using a "loop-back" local Linked Server in all three cases).

It seems that this problem has to do with *where* the query is executing, or at least where *part(s)* of it are executing. I say this because I was able to get the `CAST` operation to work, but only by including a reference to a local DB object:

```
SELECT rmt.*, CAST(NULL AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER) AS [GUID]
FROM [Local].[database_name].[dbo].[table_name] rmt
CROSS JOIN (SELECT TOP (1) 1 FROM [sys].[data_spaces]) tmp(dummy);
```

That actually works. But the following gets the original error:

```
SELECT rmt.*, CAST(NULL AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER) AS [GUID]
FROM [Local].[database_name].[dbo].[table_name] rmt
CROSS JOIN (VALUES (1)) tmp(dummy);
```

I am guessing that when there are no local references, the entire query is shipped off to the remote system to be executed, and for some reason `NULL`s cannot be converted to `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER`, or perhaps the `NULL` is getting translated by the OLE DB driver incorrectly.

---

Based on the testing that I have done, this would appear to be a bug, but I'm not sure if the bug is within SQL Server or the SQL Server Native Client / OLEDB driver. However, the conversion error occurs within the OLEDB driver, and so is not necessarily an issue of converting from `INT` to `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` (a conversion which is not allowed in SQL Server) since the driver is not using SQL Server to do conversions (SQL Server also does not allow for converting `INT` to `DATE`, yet the OLEDB driver handles that successfully, as shown in one of the tests).

I ran three tests. For the two that succeeded, I looked at the XML execution plans which show the query that is being executed remotely. For all three, I captured any Exceptions or OLEDB events via SQL Profiler:

Events:

- Errors and Warnings

  - **Attention**
  - **Exception**
  - **Execution Warnings**
  - **User Error Message**
- OLEDB

  - **all**
- TSQL

  - all *except*:

    - **SQL:StmtRecompile**
    - **XQuery Static Type**

Column Filters:

- ApplicationName

  - NOT LIKE **%Intellisense%**
- SPID

  - Greater than or equal **50**

**THE TESTS**

- Test 1

  - `CAST(NULL AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)` that works

  ```
  SELECT TOP (2) CAST(NULL AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER) AS [Something]
               , (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sys.[data_spaces]) AS [lcl]
  FROM [Local].[TEMPTEST].[sys].[objects] rmt;
  ```

  Relevant portion of the XML execution plan:

  ```xml
            <DefinedValue>
              <ColumnReference Column="Expr1002" />
              <ScalarOperator ScalarString="NULL">
                <Const ConstValue="NULL" />
              </ScalarOperator>
            </DefinedValue>
    ...
  <RemoteQuery RemoteSource="Local" RemoteQuery=
   "SELECT 1 FROM &quot;TEMPTEST&quot;.&quot;sys&quot;.&quot;objects&quot; &quot;Tbl1001&quot;"
   />
  ```
- Test 2

  - `CAST(NULL AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)` that fails

  ```
  SELECT TOP (2) CAST(NULL AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER) AS [Something]
           --  , (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sys.[data_spaces]) AS [lcl]
  FROM [Local].[TEMPTEST].[sys].[objects] rmt;
  ```

  (note: I kept the subquery in there, commented out, so that it would be one less difference when I compared the XML trace files)
- Test 3

  - `CAST(NULL AS DATE)` that works

  ```
  SELECT TOP (2) CAST(NULL AS DATE) AS [Something]
           --  , (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sys.[data_spaces]) AS [lcl]
  FROM [Local].[TEMPTEST].[sys].[objects] rmt;
  ```

  (note: I kept the subquery in there, commented out, so that it would be one less difference when I compared the XML trace files)

  Relevant portion of the XML execution plan:

  ```xml
            <DefinedValue>
              <ColumnReference Column="Expr1002" />
              <ScalarOperator ScalarString="[Expr1002]">
                <Identifier>
                  <ColumnReference Column="Expr1002" />
                </Identifier>
              </ScalarOperator>
            </DefinedValue>
   ...
  <RemoteQuery RemoteSource="Local" RemoteQuery=
   "SELECT TOP (2) NULL &quot;Expr1002&quot; FROM &quot;TEMPTEST&quot;.&quot;sys&quot;.&quot;objects&quot; &quot;Tbl1001&quot;" 
   />
  ```

If you look at Test #3, it is doing a `SELECT TOP (2) NULL` on the "remote" system. The SQL Profiler trace shows that the datatype of this remote field is in fact `INT`. The trace also shows that the field on the client side (i.e. where I am running the query from) is `DATE`, as expected. The conversion from `INT` to `DATE`, something which will get an error in SQL Server, works just fine within the OLEDB driver. The remote value is `NULL`, so it is returned directly, hence the `<ColumnReference Column="Expr1002" />`.

If you look at Test #1, it is doing a `SELECT 1` on the "remote" system. The SQL Profiler trace shows that the datatype of this remote field is in fact `INT`. The trace also shows that the field on the client side (i.e. where I am running the query from) is `GUID`, as expected. The conversion from `INT` to `GUID` (remember, this is done within the driver, and OLEDB calls it "GUID"), something which will get an error in SQL Server, works just fine within the OLEDB driver. The remote value is *not* `NULL`, so it is replaced with a literal `NULL`, hence the `<Const ConstValue="NULL" />`.

Test #2 fails, so there is no execution plan. However, it does query the "remote" system successfully, but just can't pass back the result set. The query that SQL Profiler captured is:

```sql
SELECT TOP (2) NULL "Expr1002" FROM "TEMPTEST"."sys"."objects" "Tbl1001"
```

That is that exact same query that is being done in Test #1, yet here it is failing. There are other minor differences, but I cannot fully interpret the OLEDB communication. However, the remote field is still showing as `INT` (wType = 3 = adInteger / four-byte signed integer / DBTYPE_I4) while the "client" field is still showing as `GUID` (wType = 72 = adGUID / globally unique identifier / DBTYPE_GUID). The OLE DB documentation doesn't help much as [GUID Data Type Conversions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms717995(v=vs.85).aspx), [DBDATE Data Type Conversions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711203(v=vs.85).aspx), and [I4 Data Type Conversions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms712997(v=vs.85).aspx) show that converting from **I4** to either **GUID** or **DBDATE** is unsupported, yet the `DATE` query works.

The Trace XML files for the three tests are located on PasteBin. If you want to see the details of where each test differs from the others, you can save them locally and then do a "diff" on them. The files are:

1. [NullGuidSuccess.xml](http://pastebin.com/ZXAQRNg6)
2. [NullGuidError.xml](http://pastebin.com/N3ULCiPd)
3. [NullDateSuccess.xml](http://pastebin.com/pFAdx4Vu)

**ERGO?**

What to do about it? Probably just the work-around I noted in the top section, given that the SQL Native Client -- `SQLNCLI11` -- is deprecated as of SQL Server 2012. Most of the MSDN pages on the topic of SQL Server Native Client have the following notice at the top:

> **Warning**
>
> SQL Server Native Client (SNAC) is not supported beyond SQL Server 2012. Avoid using SNAC in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use it. The [Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/mt654048.aspx) provides native connectivity from Windows to Microsoft SQL Server and Microsoft Azure SQL Database.

For more info, please see:

- [SQL Server Native Client](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280510.aspx)
- [Installing SQL Server Native Client](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131321.aspx)

---

**ODBC ??**

I set up an ODBC Linked Server via:

```sql
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver
  @server = N'LocalODBC',
  @srvproduct=N'{my_server_name}',
  @provider=N'MSDASQL',
  @provstr=N'Driver={SQL Server};Server=(local);Trusted_Connection=Yes;';

EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin
  @rmtsrvname=N'LocalODBC',
  @useself=N'True',
  @locallogin=NULL,
  @rmtuser=NULL,
  @rmtpassword=NULL;
```

And then tried:

```sql
SELECT CAST(NULL AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER) AS [Something]
FROM [LocalODBC].[tempdb].[sys].[objects] rmt;
```

and received the following error:

> OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "LocalODBC" returned message "Requested conversion is not supported.".
>   Msg 7341, Level 16, State 2, Line 53
>   Cannot get the current row value of column "(user generated expression).Expr1002" from OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "LocalODBC".

---

**P.S.**

As it relates to transporting GUIDs between remote and local servers, non-NULL values are handled via a special syntax. I noticed the following OLE DB Event info in the SQL Profiler trace when I ran `CAST(0x00 AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)`:

```xml
<RemoteQuery RemoteSource="Local" RemoteQuery=
 "SELECT {guid'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'} &quot;Expr1002&quot; FROM &quot;TEMPTEST&quot;.&quot;sys&quot;.&quot;objects&quot; &quot;Tbl1001&quot;" 
 />
```

**P.P.S.**

I also tested via `OPENQUERY` with the following query:

```sql
SELECT TOP (2) CAST(NULL AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER) AS [Something]
     --, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sys.[data_spaces]) AS [lcl]
FROM   OPENQUERY([Local], N'SELECT 705 AS [dummy] FROM [TEMPTEST].[sys].[objects];') rmt;
```

and it succeeded, even without the local object reference. The SQL Profiler trace XML file has been posted to PasteBin at:

[NullGuidSuccessOPENQUERY.xml](http://pastebin.com/VsXWTE30)

The XML execution plan shows it using a `NULL` constant, same as in Test #1.

Comment: I have recreated this issue on 2012 sp3-cu1.

Comment: @BobKlimes Interesting. Is that using a linked server to a 2008 R2 instance or loop-back?

Comment: remote linked server is 2008 R2 sp2 + MS15-058 (10.50.4339.0).

Comment: doesn't appear to be version related. Have tested multiple combos of 2008r2,2012,2014,2016 and all have so far produced error, even 2008r2-2008r2.

Comment: @BobKlimes You are correct. I had the `CAST` on the remote system, in a View, and _that_ works. But doing the `CAST` locally does not, at least not without a reference to a local object ;). I have updated my answer accordingly. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I have no 'absolute' proof, but I 'suspect' the problem stems from the fact that a UniqueIdentifer is server dependent and perhaps the provider is having difficulty figuring out which server (local or remote) to get this uniqueidentifier from, even though it's null.  That's why you can probably cast any other datatype successfully in this scenario, but not uniqueidentifier  Using OPENQUERY instead of 4-part name works

Comment: @srutzky This seems to be accurate; if I include a `JOIN`/`APPLY`-clause pointing to a source on the origin server it properly resolves the casts without errors. I'd apprieciate getting some confirmation or sources on whether or not this is the issue and, hopefully, why it is an issue.

Comment: What an exceedingly obscure issue. Thank you so much for the insight and research, @srutzky, it's greatly appreciated. I'll keep the decrepation of SNAC in mind for future work and fallback to the aforementioned workaround. Great work!

Comment: @krystah You are quite welcome :). I just did a little more research just to make sure that doing the `CAST(NULL AS DATE)` _with_ the local reference (even though it isn't necessary) behaves the same as the GUID with the local reference (which is necessary). And it does. But in looking over various results I found that I made a minor mistake when recording stuff. I just updated my answer to correct that. Please see the [revisions page](http://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/147603/revisions) to more easily see what changed.

Answer (score 4):

There is only an ugly workaround - use some date constant like `'1900-01-01'` instead of `null`.

```
CAST('1900-01-01' as DateTime) as Modified
```

After import you may update columns with `1900-01-01` back to Null.

This is kind of SQL 2012 feature/bug as per [here](https://sqlwithmanoj.com/2015/03/27/sqlncli11-for-linked-server-xyz-returned-message-requested-conversion-is-not-supported-sql-server-2012-upgrade-behavior-changes/).

**Edit:** replaced `1900-00-00` with valid date `1900-01-01` as per @a_horse_with_no_name comment below.

Comment: This workaround was probably worth mentioning but it may no longer be relevant now that the OP has clarified that the culprit of the problem is a `uniqueidentifier` column. Or maybe it could be adapted – something like `CAST('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' AS UniqueIdentifier) AS [GUID]`, perhaps?

Comment: Thanks guys. Casting to an empty GUID or DateTime works, but I need to understand why this is happening. It's also worth mentioning that I'm not importing anything, so there is no possibility of altering the source data.

Comment: `1900-00-00` is an invalid date and will not be accepted.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : stupid mistake, fixed.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is related to data type conversions (as hit on in the comments).

Consider the following:

```
SELECT NULL as NullColumn INTO SomeTable;
EXEC sp_help SomeTable;
DROP TABLE SomeTable;
```

Note that the `NullColumn` is of type `int`. SQL Server does not like to convert `int` values to `uniqueidentifier`. This `SELECT` statement will fail on a data type conversion:

```
--Just a SELECT from nothing
SELECT CAST(CAST(NULL as int) as uniqueidentifier);
--
--or to see it from a physical table:
SELECT NULL as NullColumn INTO SomeTable;
SELECT CAST(NullColumn as uniqueidentifier) FROM SomeTable;
DROP TABLE SomeTable;
```

> Msg 529, Level 16, State 2, Line 3
>
> Explicit conversion from data type int to uniqueidentifier is not allowed.

While this specific value (NULL) is able to be cast to a GUID, SQL Server throws the error based on the data type conversion, before even looking at the specific values. Instead, you will need to do a multi-step `CAST` operation to go change the implicit `int` to a datatype that can be converted cleanly into `uniqueidentifer`--which means casting first to `varchar` then to `uniqueidentifier`:

```
--Just a SELECT from nothing
SELECT CAST(CAST(CAST(NULL as int) as varchar) as uniqueidentifier);
--
--or to see it from a physical table:
SELECT NULL as NullColumn INTO SomeTable;
SELECT CAST(CAST(NullColumn as varchar(32)) as uniqueidentifier) FROM SomeTable;
DROP TABLE SomeTable;
```

Comment: This issue is not really due to datatype conversions, at least not within SQL Server. Details are in my [answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/147603/30859), but the conversion is being done within the OLEDB driver, not within SQL Server, and the conversion rules aren't the same.

Answer (score 1):

The OP can ultimately decide if this is an appropriate answer.

I have no 'absolute' proof, but I 'suspect' the problem stems from the fact that a UniqueIdentifer is server dependent and perhaps the provider is having difficulty figuring out which server (local or remote) to get this uniqueidentifier from, even though it's null. That's why you can probably cast any other datatype successfully in this scenario, but not uniqueidentifier. Data types that are 'server' dependent like UNIQUEIDENTIFIERS and DATETIMEOFFSET will give you the error you're encountering.

Using OPENQUERY instead of 4-part name works.

```
set nocount on  
DECLARE @cmd nVARCHAR(max)
DECLARE @datatype SYSNAME

DECLARE _CURSOR CURSOR LOCAL FORWARD_ONLY STATIC READ_ONLY
FOR
SELECT NAME
FROM sys.types 

OPEN _CURSOR

FETCH NEXT
FROM _CURSOR
INTO @datatype

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        SET @cmd = 'select top 1 cast(null as ' + @Datatype + ') as CastedData from remoteserver.remotedatabase.remoteschema.remotetable'
        PRINT @cmd
        EXECUTE sp_executesql @cmd
    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH
        PRINT Error_message()
    END CATCH

FETCH NEXT
FROM _CURSOR
INTO @datatype
END --End While

CLOSE _CURSOR

DEALLOCATE _CURSOR
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `Uniqueidentifier` and `DateTimeOffset` being server-dependent? Do you have any sources for this?

Comment: @krystah - From this link (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190215(v=sql.105).aspx)

"The uniqueidentifier data type stores 16-byte binary values that operate as globally unique identifiers (GUIDs). A GUID is a unique binary number; no other computer in the world will generate a duplicate of that GUID value. The main use for a GUID is for assigning an identifier that must be unique in a network that has many computers at many sites."

Comment: For DateTimeOffSet (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630289.aspx) Defines a date that is combined with a time of a day that has time zone awareness and is based on a 24-hour clock

Comment: I am 'inferring' that, since these two data types 'seem' to be the only ones that give the error in your scenario and those data types are 'server-dependent', that is the reason for your problem.  If you use OPENQUERY to retrieve your results from your view and add the additional null casts, it should work because the provider knows 'where' to get that information

Comment: @krystah and Scott: these two datatypes are not server-dependent, at least not in how you are describing and implying. GUIDs are "architecture" dependent in terms of their underlying binary representation (see [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/121878/30859) for details), but if that was an issue here, then no GUIDs would transfer properly. For DATETIMEOFFSET, that only knows of an offset, not of an actual Time Zone / TimeZoneID. While both use system info to generate new values, no new values are being generated here, and if they were, they wouldn't be generated in the provider.

Comment: @srutsky - then, I guess I'm puzzled why those two data types are the only ones failing in my example using 4part name, but happily come over using open query - my thought was remote guid would never be local guid, so my thought was that the provider could not discern which guid you wanted, but open query worked by forcing the guid to come from remote- as I said, I have no absolute proof of my answer, but it "seemed" plausible- I'm still not sure anyone has determined the exact cause if the problem- I'm just throwing out ideas

Comment: @krystah and Scott: If there is a GUID value, then it would come across correctly, and if a translation of the binary form was needed, it would do that. If not, selecting any UNIQUEIDENTIFIER value would not work correctly. I have added SQL Profiler trace output to my answer which shows some of what is going on. I have also added some info regarding how GUIDs are transported (using an empty -- 0x00 -- GUID). Again, the difference between servers for GUIDs is merely in their generation. Once generated, they are just 16 byte binary values.

Comment: @krystah and Scott: From what I have found (and put into my answer), it _looks_ like a bug in SQL Server since it passes in a different query to the provider based on the existence of a local object reference, even though that subquery isn't even part of the "remote" query.  I think it will take looking at the SQL Server source code to determine the exact cause, though, and that's not about to happen ;-).

Comment: i've done some further testing on my hypothesis, and I don't think my is the correct answer after all :( - @srutsky has done a lot more analysis on this issue than I have and I will defer to his expertise. This has been a most interesting question, so I'm upvoting the question.

Comment: Hey guys, I just want to thank you both for all the effort and insight, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: [The accepted answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/147603/62203) seems to indicate that the conversion needs to happen locally because the OLEDB driver doesn't support it.

So I think a simple workaround (at least in the case of my query which is selecting a null `uniqueidentifier` in the base case of a recursive CTE) is to declare a null variable:

```
declare @nullGuid as uniqueidentifier = null;

--Instead of...
CAST(NULL AS UniqueIdentifier) AS [GUID]

--use
@nullGuid AS [GUID]
```